# Sublime Autocompletion for HTML using Emmet inside .sublime-autocompletion file

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext3, emmet

I tried to create a auto completion with scope of html file. But it is not working...
Can somebody please, find the problem...

```
{
    "scope": "text.html.php.htm",

    "completions":
    [
        { "trigger": "tta", "contents": ".tabs>ul>(li>a[href='#tabs-$'])*3^^(#tabs-$>p)*3" },
        { "trigger": "accd", "contents": ".accordion>(h4{section$}+#first$>p)*4" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The scopes should be separated by comma: `text.html,source.php` should work. Complete list of scopes is here: https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378

Comment: I tried to change the scope, but it is not working. when ever i press `ctrl+space`, it disappears. I think the dot(.) or some other character is playing real. Is there some escape character to escape preserved character.

Comment: The `$` characters seems to be causing it, though I'm not sure why. It works when you escape them like so: `\\$`.

Comment: Thank you very much, It is working properly now, it is helping me a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help :) Btw, I posted the solution as an answer, could you mark it as accepted if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem are the scopes. They must be separated by commas and also the scope for PHP source is `source.php`, not `text.php`. You can find complete list of scopes [here](https://gist.github.com/iambibhas/4705378).

You must also escape the `$` characters as `\\$` otherwise the completion will produce nothing when invoked. I'm not exactly sure why this happens. Anyone feel free to update this answer if you know the reason behind this.